# Jquery version for $("#submit").on("click", function(){

Tags: jquery

Does anybody know when

```
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
```

came out. Meaning what version of Jquery started using the .on()

Comment: Seriously? Let's look at http://api.jquery.com/on/: *"version added: 1.7"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live().](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> `.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )` **version added: 1.7**